# Confused about AddApplicationPart(...), everything seems to be working without it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, asp.net-core-mvc

I am confused about the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationPart(myClassLibraryAssembly);
```

I am referencing an other ASP.NET class library in this project (My.Class.Library), and controllers from that class library are working fine (handling requests properly) in this very project even if I comment out this code:

```
// builder.Services.AddApplicationPart(myClassLibraryAssembly);
```

I do understand that the concept of FeatureProvider can fine tune what is exposed, and also may give metadata... but what would be the use case implementing a controller in a *class library* and not to expose it for usage? ...and again all controllers are working out of the box without even the traces of Application Part architecture.

What am I missing?